# Image Clarity Loses When Product Detail Page Is Loaded - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Sometimes when we load the product detail page, Product image size of 100x100 is loaded from cache. The product main image seems to be blurred. 
Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Shop URL - http://b2bdev.globalfootcare.com.au/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to some unwanted JS files from 3rd party plugins. The JS was taking so much time for loading and it prevented the main image file from loading and hence it loaded the small thumbnail image from cache. We resolved the issue by optimizing the Js file of the plugin.

Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a link to your side, but I still found the site. Please edit your question and add a link.

On my system with a fast connection, I need 20 seconds to load your page with more the 350 elements (js, CSS, graphics).

I suppose sometimes your script files reach a timeout for waiting on a resource. You should try to reduce your side by combining scripts, CSS files, and removing obsolete content. Is there any chance to do this?

You can track network events for a timeout, for example, with the developer tools of your browser.

Regards, Mario

Comment: I have updated the link. The issues is happening randomly. The scenario is as follows : Take PDP of products randomly, at some PDP pages the image will be blurred and 100x100 cached image will be loaded. http://b2bdev.globalfootcare.com.au/accessories/accessories/all-accessories.html

Comment: Providing a har-file would be helpful. You should open developer tools from your browser with active network tab. Then you can try to reproduce the problem. After you got it, you can first save a HAR-file ([Instructions](https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Content-Troubleshooting/How-to-Generate-Network-Captures-for-Troubleshooting/ta-p/366)). You can load a HAR file via drag&drop into network tab to compare different snapshots or share that files with us.